# Showing $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt[3]{q})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}\sqrt[3]{q})$.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $p$ and $q$ be prime numbers, $p\neq q$.

Now I have to show $L:=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt[3]{q})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}\sqrt[3]{q})=:K$.

The direction $K\subseteq L$ is clear. For the other direction I have to show that $\sqrt{p}\in K$ and $\sqrt[3]{q}\in K$. Thats where I'm at at the moment.

Can someone please give me a hint on how to show this?

Comment: For the other inclusion take the one generator, raised to the powers two and three.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint $(\sqrt p \sqrt[3]{q})^3=qp\sqrt p$

Comment: It's $qp\sqrt p$.